# Guice Multibindings and proguard

Tags: proguard, roboguice, guice-3

Im trying to use roboguice+guice multibindings for android. When I skip proguard the app is working well. When proguard is on I got runtime errors like:

```
Multibinder is not initialized
```

The proguard.properties is set up correctly for the standard roboguice library. It went wrong when I added the Multibindings extensions.

Has anyone worked with these?

Comment: Can you provide your proguard configuration file?

Comment: Actually I've solved this somehow, but forgot about this question. I'm gonna post the answer soon.